# Python: Counting frequency of symbols in list

Tags: python, list, frequency

I have a list named 'words' that contains coded words (in symbols):

```
['#+/084&"', '#3*#%#+', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.#7&33&', '#*#71%', "&-&641'2", '#))85', '9&330*']
```

I need to be able to print out the frequency of the symbols used throughout the whole list. I have tried using 'Counter' from 'collections'. However, it treats each item in the list as a single element and not each individual symbol in the list (as shown below):

```
Counter({"&-&641'2": 1, '#))85': 1, '!-*%': 1, '8%203:': 1, ',1$&': 1, '9&330*': 1, '#*#71%': 1, '#+/084&"': 1, '#3*#%#+': 1, '.#7&33&': 1})
```

Is there a way to get the counter to count each individual symbol?

Comment: You will have to reduce the list to a single string, e.g. with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score 1):

You need to join your strings together then use `Counter` :

```
>>> Counter(''.join(l))
Counter({'#': 8, '&': 7, '3': 6, '%': 4, '*': 4, '1': 3, '0': 3, '8': 3, ')': 2, '+': 2, '-': 2, '2': 2, '4': 2, '7': 2, '!': 1, '"': 1, '$': 1, "'": 1, ',': 1, '/': 1, '.': 1, '5': 1, '6': 1, '9': 1, ':': 1})
```

Comment: Or use `reduce(operator.or_, map(Counter, l), Counter())` to produce a union of counters per element... :-P

Comment: Or apply Python's "flatten" function to the list, which goes by the unfortunate name `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`.

Comment: Or use the *other* flatten option with a generator expression, `Counter(c for elem in l for c in elem)`.

Comment: @Sven: That only flattens one level, so calling it `flatten()` would be confusing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `reduce(operator.or_, map(Counter, l), Counter())` was an interesting idea ! :)